# iframe youtube api dynamically change video source

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I am trying to change iframe source everytime user click on the skip button and it doesn't work.

```html
        var player;
        window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
          alert('called onYouTubePlayerAPIReady');
          player = new YT.Player('header-video__video-element', {
            events: {
              'onStateChange': ShowMe
            }
          });
        }


        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        function ShowMe() {

          var sStatus;
          sStatus = player.getPlayerState();

          if (sStatus == -1) alert("Video has not started.");
          else if (sStatus == 0) {  
            $('#ytplayer').replaceWith('<a href="page/" target="_blank"><img class="special_hover" src="image" alt="" /></a>')
          }
          else if (sStatus == 1) {
      } //Video is playing
      else if (sStatus == 2) {
      }  
      else if (sStatus == 3) {
        } //video is buffering 
        else if (sStatus == 5) {
      } //Video is cued.
    }
    


   //CODE TRIGGERED BY BUTTON
   $(this.settings.playTrigger).on('click', function(e) {
    alert('changing source');
    $("#header-video__video-element").attr('src', "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eozsR79JjPM");
        //document.getElementById('header-video__video-element').setAttribute('src', "https://www.youtube.com/embed/eozsR79JjPM");
        alert('changed');
        //player.loadVideoById("95CX2VL0hVY");
       // e.preventDefault();
       // that.appendIframe();
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

The player.loadVideoById method that you commented out should do the work. Here is a working example of a little application I did

```
//Code from the YouTube iFrame API doc   
//https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference
var player; 
var id = "V13MbW3oMUw";

  //Init API
  window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '720',
      width: '960',
      videoId: "JxfzRNA2_8M",
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      }
    });
  };

// Launch video as it's ready
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

 //Change video onclick
 $("#button").click(function(id){player.loadVideoById(id);});
```

Comment: Sometimes, you just need to reload the page for it to load

Comment: How to give dynamic width and height?